# How do i save POST Jquery results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this $.Post

```
function getEmail() {
var dateobj = new Date();
var B = dateobj.toISOString();
var Method = "getSurveysByEmail";
var hash = SHA1(Method + getCookie("userEmail") + B + getCookie("APIKey"));
var requestBody = {
    'method': Method,
    'email': getCookie("SelectedEntryEmail"),
    'authentication': {
        'accountID': getCookie("userID"),
        'username': getCookie("userEmail"),
        'hash': hash,
        'datetime': B
    },
    'take': 1,
    'skip': 0
};
$.post('https://surveymechanics.com/api/invitees', JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    function (data, status) {
        if (status == "success") {
                 setCookie("SurveyByEmail", JSON.stringify(data["data"]["surveys"]), 1);
        } else {
            sessionStorage.setItem('SurveyByEmail', JSON.stringify(data['data']['surveys']));
        }
    });
```

}

Basicaly checking the network debug, i can see the results for this POST and is a success (as you can see here https://prnt.sc/skddut);

However the code just pass through the

```
 function (data, status) {
        if (status == "success") {
            alert('hahahahaha');
        } else {
            sessionStorage.setItem('SurveyByEmail', JSON.stringify(data['data']['surveys']));
        }
    });
```

and doesnt save any cookies or save on storage was trying to setup a cookie.

Comment: Add a `console.log(status);console.log(data)` before the `if(status` to actually have a look at what you've got (or use proper debugging)

Comment: A side question: what does you want to achive with `JSON.stringify(requestBody)`?

Comment: was a old code, it was using XHR http request before.

Comment: I also used the console.log, and im currently using firefox Developer edition for debugging javascript, the code just pass through the whole Function call back.

Comment: Then it's probably not getting to the success callback (rather than "passing through") - add a .fail promise handler.  Note: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ *"If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail silently"*

Comment: I added the code from the jquery website, however it also passes through it without checking the code. remember that the POST is status success on the Network debug. as i posted on the screenshot, There is an exactly same method in another part of the code and it does work normal. only this one i dont know why dosnt run the Function callback

Comment: The screenshot is unclear. Where did you capture that data from exactly? Please show the actual Network tab entry for the call to `surveymechanics.com/api/invitees`

Comment: I Figure out the problem, the api Returning anwser was status : OK instead of success
error on their API (they are also developing it) so it didnt call the callback function because it answer for the sucess tag.